# JavaScript counter, count to 3 when certain <div> is reached

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having hard time with this problem. So I got counter which I want slowly to count from 0 - 3 after user has scrolled down page and reached certain class, in my case ".domov2"

If I remove API (EventListener), then counter works great, but it already starts counting immediately after site loads.

I managed to do that, but instead of executing 1 time when I scroll down, the function executes like really many times for scroll after div has been reached (I'm really bad with API). How do I limit function to execute 1 time and keep it running with only condition.

HTML:

```html
<section class="domov2">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium quis, sem.
</section>

<div id="counter" data-target="3">
-1
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.domov2').offset().top + $('.domov2').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {
        // create function startCount()
const startCount = function() {
    // get number value from data-target and current number
    const target = +counter.getAttribute('data-target');
    const count = +counter.innerText;

    // if count<target 
    if (count < target) {
        // add to current value +1
        var sestevek = count + 1
        // replace current value in html with recently updated value "sestevek"
        counter.innerText = sestevek;
        // slow down condition for 0.3s
        setTimeout(startCount, 300);
    } else {
        //if current value is = target, then keep target
        counter.innerText = target;
    }};
    
    //execute function
    startCount();
    }
});
```

Comment: Use a basic flag: `let countStarted = false;` somewhere outside. Then you use `if (!countStarted) startCount(); countStarted = true; }`

Answer (score 0):

Chris G thank you very much i succeeded, counter works perfect now, thx to your help!

Updated JavaScript:

```
let countStarted = false;

function somefunction(){
if (countStarted == false){
// create function startCount()
const startCount = function() {
  // get number value from data-target and current number
  const target = +counter.getAttribute('data-target');
  const count = +counter.innerText;
  countStarted = true;
  // if count<target 
  if (count < target) {
      // add to current value +1
      var sestevek = count + 1
      // replace current value in html with recently updated value "sestevek"
      counter.innerText = sestevek;
      // slow down condition for 0.3s
      setTimeout(startCount, 300);
  } else {
      //if current value is = target, then keep target
      counter.innerText = target;
  }};

  //execute function
  startCount();
}}
//execute somefuntion() when div class comes into view area
$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
  if($(window).scrollTop() >= $('.domov2').offset().top + $('.domov2').outerHeight() - window.innerHeight) {
      somefunction()
  }});
```